# regular expression basics - [^.]

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to understand the following regular expression which gets the domain name out of a URL

$host = "www.php.net"

```
// get last two segments of host name
preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $host, $matches);
echo "domain name is: {$matches[0]}\n";
```

how is $matches[0] coming as php.net ?

I am stuck with the patter [^.].  ^ means complimentary and . means any char. so
what does [^.] mean? complimentary of any char? Please help

Comment: Also might be better to use [parse_url](http://us.php.net/parse_url)

Comment: @Class Using parse_url won't help him learn regular expression basics.

Comment: A good resource for learning what things mean in a regexp is regexr.com. Hover your mouse over the regexp and it will display the meaning in a tooltip.

Comment: Special characters loose their special meaning inside a character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be tricky if you're new to it.

`.` normally means any non-space character. In a range (`[]`), however, it reverts to its literal meaning, i.e. a full stop (period, if you're American.)

`^` normally means "anchor to the start of the string." In a range, however, when it's the first character in that range, it flips the logic, so rather than the range representing the allowed characters, it represents the DISallowed characters.

So the pattern `'/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/'` says:

1. Match a sequence of one or more non-space characters that are not periods (the host)
2. Match a period thereafter
3. Match another sequence of one or more non-space characters that are not periods
   (the suffix)
4. The `$` anchors this to the end of the string, so steps 1-3 must be in sequence right up to the last character of the string.

Incidentally, it's not exactly a water-tight pattern for hostname matching. It doesn't take into account sub-domains or country-specific domains with more than one period (e.g. ".co.uk"), to name two points.

Comment: Minor clarification: `^` only has special meaning inside a range when it's the _first_ character.

Comment: Quite right. My laziness. Edited.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to understand your answer with the following code (host is: www.php.net)

preg_match('/([^.]+)\.[^.]+$/', $host, $matches);
echo "domain name is: {$matches[1]}\n";

Output is php. But shouldn't it be wwww because we are saying any but not a dot ?
Or probably the $ char is forcing it to parse from end?

Comment: thanks, it is clear now. if i remove $, it is coming as www. so $ does the trick of forcing it from the end

Answer (score 2):

You understood it wrong. When dot (.) is INSIDE a bracket it means a DOT, not any char. So, [^.] means every character that is not a dot.

Comment: did u mean when . is inside square brackets []?

Comment: Yes. It changes its meaning inside a square bracket []

Answer (score 1):

In a character class (`[]`) a dot means just that: a liteal dot `.`.

So `[^.]` means any character except a dot/period.